# Ionic Grid Inside Custom Component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4 and am trying to utilize the ionic grid in my custom component, but the "col-*" grid attribute doesn't seem to have any effect. I always get two columns in my row and then it wraps. (I'm setting col-4, so I would expect three columns).

Here's my code, I have no custom styles. All i've styles so far is the theme colors. I also tried the old width-10 format to no avail.

I have an ionic "page" *search.page.html* that has the following code

```
<ion-content padding color="dark">
   <app-search></app-search>
</ion-content>
```

I then created a component with the following TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MoviesService } from '../../services/movies.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})

export class SearchComponent {
  searchResults$;

  constructor(private movieService: MoviesService) {};

  search($event) {
    let searchTerm = $event.target.value;

    this.movieService.searchMovies(searchTerm).subscribe(response => {
      this.searchResults$ = response.json();
    });
  }
}
```

Then finally, here is the component HTML:

```
<ion-searchbar color="light" (search)="search($event)" placeholder="Find Movies"></ion-searchbar>

<ion-grid *ngIf="searchResults$">
  <ion-row wrap>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let result of searchResults$.results" col-4>
      <ion-card color="dark" no-margin>
        <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/{{ result.poster_path }}"/>
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-card-title>
            {{ result.title }} <span>({{ result.release_date | date: "yyyy" }})</span>
          </ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Basically with ionic 4, you don't use col-4 or width-25. You use size="4"

Answer (score 1):

I think you've implemented the component wrong.

`<ion-content padding color="dark">
   <div class="app-search-form"></div>
</ion-content>`

replace `<div class="app-search-form"></div>` with `<search></search>`

Comment: Oops! That was actually me trying something to see if it would help. I updated the code back to (what I think?) is the normal way of doing it. Lemme know if it still looks off!